# Excel/VBA update cell every time value in another cell changes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA. I have a cell in the worksheet that live updates a value. the Value changes about once every month. Is there a way for me to record the day that the value changed in an adjacent cell? 
For example,
If the value in A1 changes from 5 to 6 today, I just want to record today's date in A2.

I don't really need to keep a record of previous changes.

Thank you so much!

Comment: worksheet_change event should help, but, think on how the value is added to A1, could it just be done in here?

Comment: Would cell **A1** contain a *Formula* or a *Typed Value* ??

Comment: it's technically a bloomberg function that live updates values @Gary'sStudent

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Bloomberg function in cell **A1** like *BDP()* or *BDH()* or *BDS()*, then you could use the `Worksheet_Calculate()` event macro to detect changes in that cell.

In this example, I use cell **A3** as a "memory" to avoid re-posting the date too often:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If [A1] <> [A3] Then
            [A3] = Range("A1").Value
            [A2] = Date
            MsgBox "Date recorded"
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Worksheet_Change()` is being fired when something on the sheet changes its value, so add something like this to your Sheet-Codemodule:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then

    Debug.Print "A1 has been changed!"
    'do something
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! ill give it a try

Answer (score 1):

***Update:***

It seems you need the calculate event also as you're using a formula. you could try something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    DoEvents

    With Range("A1")
        .Value = .Value
        DoEvents
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Range("A2").Value = Date
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: So this worked wonderfully when i typed in a different value, but the cell A1 contains a formula that autoupdates

Comment: @casualprogrammer I noticed Gary's Student picked up on that before me - makes it a lot more difficult if you don't have access to the source code for the bloomberg fnuction

Comment: I thought I could just have a cell in A3 that takes A1's value whenever it autoupdates, something like =A1 or =Value(A1) and just use the code run it on A3 instead. But that didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Worksheet_SelectionChange event. I guess it depends on what else you're doing in the worksheet as to whether it would fire or not.
You'd have to compare the value in A1 against what was in A1 previously which would be stored in another cell.